# Java TextField Date auto fill

Tags: java, codenameone, date

Alright I got something like this:

```
public void menu() {

        final Form menu = new Form("Menu");
        menu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Button confirm = new Button("Confirm");

        Container creditCardContainer = new Container(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        final TextField num1 = new TextField(3);
        final TextField num2 = new TextField(3);
        final TextField num3 = new TextField(3);

        num1.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);
        num2.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);
        num3.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);

        creditCardContainer.addComponent(num1);
        creditCardContainer.addComponent(num2);
        creditCardContainer.addComponent(num3);

        Validator v = new Validator();

        v.addConstraint(num1, new LengthConstraint(2));
        v.addConstraint(num2, new LengthConstraint(2));
        v.addConstraint(num3, new LengthConstraint(4));

         automoveToNext(num1, num2);
         automoveToNext(num2, num3);

        menu.add(creditCardContainer);
        menu.add(confirm);
        v.addSubmitButtons(confirm);
        menu.show();

            confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
                {
                    String getdate = num1.getText() + "/" + num2.getText() + "/" + num3.getText();
                    System.out.println(getdate);
                    new StateMachine("/theme");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void automoveToNext(final TextField current, final TextField next) {
        current.addDataChangedListener(new DataChangedListener() {
            public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
                if(current.getText().length() == 3) {
                    Display.getInstance().stopEditing(current);
                    String val = current.getText();
                    current.setText(val.substring(0, 2));
                    next.setText(val.substring(2));
                    Display.getInstance().editString(next, 3, current.getConstraint(), next.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Notice that `addDataChangeListener` is deprecated so I had to change it to `addDataChangedListener` instead.

I think there is something wrong in my code, because when I run it in the Codename One Simulator, it still allow me to type letters, even with the code below:

```
num1.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);
num2.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);
num3.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);
```

Also when I finish typing the date, my confirm button doesn't get highlighted as it should be. Please someone help me to fix it.

Obs: My date is intended to be dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Not really related, but I was wondering why you weren't doing this in swing?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Because I'm using Codename One framework. Instead of doing it by a GUI, I need the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't support direct field masking as native text field input doesn't handle that very well. You have 2 options I can think of:

- Use Date Picker which launches a great device native UI to pick the date. Notice it's not great in the simulator but on Android/iOS it would look good.
- Use 3 text fields and automatically move to the next as you type like we did for this credit card input sample: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/validation-regex-masking.html

Comment: You need to ask these as separate question/issues in stackoverflow. Constraint doesn't limit input type, it just hints on the virtual keyboard type. You can type anything there. You can use the datachange listener and set the text to something else as the user types if an invalid character is set

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = format.parse("");
}catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Wrong format.");
}
```

to check if the date is valid format.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, I already have this method to check if is a valid date. Looks like Codename One doesn't have a TextField Constraint for Date.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @OleV.V. If I'm not mistaken there is no `DateTimeFormatter` in Codename One API.